# DPI-1047 "libclntsh" cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: django, nginx, centos, gunicorn, cx-oracle

I have a django application hosted in centos os. Below is the configuration:-

```
Python:- 3.7.2
Django:- 1.11.18
cx_Oracle:- 7
Oracle Instant Client:- 12.1
OS:- centos
Oracle Version:- 11g
WSGI Server:- Gunicorn
Reverse Proxy Server:- Nginx
```

When I import cx_Oracle from the python3 shell, it works.
But when I start my application, on every redirect from within the application I get the same error.
Not sure what to do about it.
I dont know what code to post for this, so if any of you want to see some particular code snippet then let me know, I will edit and add that portion of the code.
I have been working on it for two days without any progress, would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using the following command. This command is necessary when you have only installed the oracle client and not the oracle db as a whole.

```
sudo sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf”
sudo ldconfig
```

Read ldconfig to understand why this command works. bash_profiles are not accessible by the server and hence merely setting oracle_home in bash_profile will not work.